Mexican Hat Challenge, #メキシカンハットチャレンジ
The hashtag #メキシカンハットチャレンジ* appeared on my X/twitter feed today. Japanese hackers have been drawing the "Mexican Hat Potential" 3D curve on all sorts of devices. My investigations also found this helpful picture of a guy wearing one of these "hats".
The hat shape is generated by the equation  
$$
z=\sin {\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}  }
$$
with \$x,y\$ ranges of \$[-4,4]\$.
Or in polar co-ordinates: \$z = f(r,\theta) = \sin r\$.
The Challenge
Draw the 3-D "Mexican Hat" surface in your language! The more obscure the language or device, the better. This is a popularity-contest.
Examples




IchigoJam BASIC 




*メキシカンハットチャレンジ literally translates to "Mexican Hat Challenge"
*Alternate link for non X users
Sandbox

I will accept a "winner" in a few days, but really you're all winners :)

Sorry, but it's a -1 from me for being a popcon.

ZX Spectrum Basic
Very Slow Program

Output

Less Slow Program

Output

Sorry for source screenshots but I was too lazy to retype everything.

Can't beat the classics. Maybe slow, but nice graph.

Not sure I ever knew / understood the syntax well enough to do this. Can't recall seeing  steps used like that and I never thought of saving my programs for future reference

J plot
plot _4 4([;;)'1 o.|@j.'

For more information on how function plots work, see wiki/Plot/Function. For the golfers, this is 24 bytes.
plot _4 4([;;)'1 o.|@j.'
              '1 o.|@j.'   NB. string repr of a dyadic fork used by plot
                   |@j.    NB. magnitude of the complex number xjy
               1 o.        NB. sin
     _4 4                  NB. plot range
         ([;;)             NB. dyadic fork
            ;              NB. build a boxed list of _4 4 and the function string
          [                NB. _4 4
           ;               NB. box again
plot                       NB. plot



That is a beautiful hat!

Microsoft Excel
This is not at all optimized for character count, but that's not really a criterion for this one anyway.
Speed Optimizations:

Originally, I had a plot function that plotted a single point at a time. This required copying the entire "canvas" every time I wanted to plot a point, which was O(n2m2), where n and m are canvas and sample area widths respectively.
Then I realized I could just make a sorted lookup table for the points (sort is both for depth buffer and lookup efficiency). Now it's O(n2 log(m) + m2), assuming the sort is sub-O(m2) and sorted lookups is O(log m).
Sorting by numeric values is way faster than sorting by text values, which is why I'm multiplying by 1000. Using a comma-separated string takes over twice as long.
MATCH with 2 INDEXes is about 2x faster than 2 VLOOKUPs.

=LET(
 tableWidth,80,
 resX,0.0625,resY,0.0625,
 width,8,
 dimX,width/resX,
 dimY,width/resY, thX,RADIANS(30),
 thZ,RADIANS(60),
 scale,8,
 sX,SIN(thX),cX,COS(thX),
 sZ,SIN(thZ),cZ,COS(thZ),
 rotMatrix,VSTACK(
  HSTACK(cX,-sX*cZ,sX*sZ),
  HSTACK(sX,cX*cZ,-cX*sZ),
  HSTACK(0,sZ,cZ)
 ),
 z,LAMBDA(i,j,SIN(SQRT(i*i+j*j))),
 plotAll,LAMBDA(pts,
  LET(
   zBufs,MAP(pts,LAMBDA(pt,0+INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(pt,"|"),1))),
   coords,MAP(pts,LAMBDA(pt,0+INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(pt,"|"),2))),
   vals,MAP(pts,LAMBDA(pt,0+INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(pt,"|"),3))),
   sorted,SORT(SORT(HSTACK(zBufs,coords,vals),1,1),2,1),
   indexCol,CHOOSECOLS(sorted,2),
   valueCol,CHOOSECOLS(sorted,3),
   MAKEARRAY(tableWidth,tableWidth,LAMBDA(row,col,
    LET(
     id,1000*col+row,
     check,MATCH(id,indexCol,1),
     IF(IFNA(INDEX(indexCol,check),2)=id,INDEX(valueCol,check),"")
    )
   ))
  )
 ),
 plotAll(
  TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(dimX,dimY,LAMBDA(row,col,
   LET(
    i,(col-1)*resX-width/2,
    j,(row-1)*resY-width/2,
    k,z(i,j),
    newPt,MMULT(rotMatrix,VSTACK(i*scale,j*scale,k*scale)),
    INDEX(newPt,3)&"|"
     &(1000*ROUND(40+INDEX(newPt,1),0)
      +ROUND(30+INDEX(newPt,2),0))&"|"
     &k
   )
  )))
 )
)

Screenshot for amusement:

I added a Color Scale formatter for ease of viewing.
Google Sheets port
=LET(
 tableWidth,80,
 resX,0.0625,resY,0.0625,
 width,8,
 dimX,width/resX,
 dimY,width/resY,
 thX,RADIANS(30),
 thZ,RADIANS(60),
 scale,8,
 sX,SIN(thX),cX,COS(thX),
 sZ,SIN(thZ),cZ,COS(thZ),
 rotMatrix,{
  {cX,-sX*cZ,sX*sZ};
  {sX,cX*cZ,-cX*sZ};
  {0,sZ,cZ}
 },
 z,LAMBDA(i,j,SIN(SQRT(i*i+j*j))),
 plotAll,LAMBDA(pts,
  LET(
   sorted,SORT(pts,1,1,2,1),
   indexCol,CHOOSECOLS(sorted,1),
   valueCol,CHOOSECOLS(sorted,3),
   MAKEARRAY(tableWidth,tableWidth,LAMBDA(row,col,
    LET(
     id,1000*col+row,
     check,MATCH(id,indexCol,1),
     IF(IFNA(INDEX(indexCol,check),2)=id,INDEX(valueCol,check),"")
    )
   ))
  )
 ),
 plotAll(
  MAKEARRAY(dimX*dimY,1,LAMBDA(ptNo,_,
   LET(
    i,MOD(ptNo,dimX)*resX-width/2,
    j,INT(ptNo/dimX)*resY-width/2,
    k,z(i,j),
    newPt,MMULT(rotMatrix,VSTACK(i*scale,j*scale,k*scale)),
    {1000*ROUND(40+INDEX(newPt,1),0)
      +ROUND(30+INDEX(newPt,2),0),INDEX(newPt,3),k}
   )
  ))
 )
)

Port notes:

Google Sheets SORT is capable of multi-column sort. All it needs is the column indexes, which is nice.
Sheets accepts variables in array literals, so no need to do as many H/VSTACKs. There's just the one I can't get rid of because it errors for some reason.
You can also return nested arrays with array lambdas, so no need to do any parsing.
Google Sheets' render time is faster than Excel's somehow (theweb-app seems to be about as fast as the Desktop version). Whatever Google is doing in its lookup algorithms, it's much more optimized.


MATL
KUQ_ZvqK/t!YyY,lYH

Try it at MATL Online!
Some obscure features:

The code does not use any numeric characters;
The hat plot is rather dark;
The language itself?

How it works
KUQ   % Push 4, square, add 1: gives 17
_Zv   % Symmetric range: gives row vector [17 16 ... 2 1 2 ... 16 17]
q     % Subtract 1, element-wise: gives [16 15 ... 1 0 1 ... 15 16]
K/    % Divide by 4, element-wise: gives [4. 3.75 ... 0.25 0 0.25 ... 3.75 4]
t!    % Duplicate, transpose
Yy    % Hypotenuse (square root of sum of squares), with implicit expansion.
      % Gives a square matrix
Y,    % Sine, element-wise
lYH   % Plot as surface


That was quick!

Wolfram Language (Mathematica)
Plot3D[Sin@Norm@{,y},{,-4,4},{y,-4,4}]

Mostly the obvious implementation, although Norm is a short way to access the square root of the sum of squares, and I did remember to save 2 bytes by letting one of the variables be the invisible Nulls before the commas (not that this is code-golf, but habits die hard) :p


not that this is code-golf, but habits die hard And it does feel weird not to see the byte count in the title :-)

Nice image  . Third shortest code...

Thumby MicroPython
import thumby
import math
while 1:
    m=[-100]*72
    thumby.display.fill(0)
    ry=(y/4 for y in range(-16, 17))
    for y in ry:
        a=2*y
        rx=(x/4 for x in range(-16, 17))
        for x in rx:
            z=12*math.sin(math.sqrt(x*x+y*y))
            x1=int(x*4+a)
            y1=int(z+a)
            if y1>m[x1]:
                m[x1]=y1
                thumby.display.setPixel(x1+36,18-y1,1)
    thumby.display.update()

Thumby is a tiny device the size of your thumb, programmed in Micropython with 72x40 pixel black & white screen.
Try the above code by copy/pasting into the emulator here and clicking RESTART (assuming your browser can cope - works with most Chrome based browsers)


Nice. This is what I was going for in the question.

YASEPL
this is a translation of Neil's answer in ZX Spectrum BASIC. really cool dude!
=i£1`1!1©0!+}2,255$-5`2=j-4`3!o$j^!z$i^+o&≈0,z!o$j*4!x$i*16+128-o!o$j*8!l$z*32!y$i*2+96+o+l!q$x(!r$y(!t¥q,1}5,y,4!1¤x,y!p$27›$91›!r/3(!n$50-r~!p$59›!q/2(~#"H">"o"`4!h$/4!j+h}2,4,3!h$/16!i+h}2,4,2

how it works:
=i£1`1!1©0!+}2,255                           - create list1 with 255 0s
$-5                                          - set I to -4
`2                                           - do {
=j-4                                         -     set J to -4
`3                                           -     do {
!o$j^!z$i^+o&≈0,z                            -         set Z to sin(sqrt(I^2+J^2))
!o$j*4!x$i*16+128-o                          -         set X to (I*16)+128-(J*4)
!o$j*8!l$z*32!y$i*2+96+o+l                   -         set Y to (I*2)+96+(J*8)+(Z*32)
!q$x(!r$y(                                   -         set Q & R to integer versions of X and Y
!t¥q,1}5,y,4                                 -         if list1(Q) < Y {
!1¤x,y                                       -             set list1(X) to Y
!p$27›$91›!r/3(!n$50-r~!p$59›!q/2(~#"H">"o"  -             plot Q and R on places on the screen
`4                                           -         }
!h$/4!j+h                                    -         J += 0.25
}2,4,3                                       -     } while J < 4
!h$/16!i+h                                   -     I += 0.0625
}2,4,2                                       - } while I > 4



strange source code, nice output!

HTML+CSS
The animation, depending on device performance, might give a few artifacts and obscure a bit which ring is drawn in front of which one. (which actually is fine, since otherwise it might be more obvious this solution is not really perfect.)
Edit: Tweaked the nature of the animation and the order of the rings in such a way that they are now mostly correctly aligned.


@property --r {
  syntax: "<number>";
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.base {
  width: 400px;
  animation: grow 1s linear infinite;
}
.ring {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(-20deg);
}
.ring::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: calc((var(--s) + var(--r)) * 100px);
  height: calc((var(--s) + var(--r)) * 100px);
  top: calc(200px - (var(--s) + var(--r)) * 50px);
  left: calc(200px - (var(--s) + var(--r)) * 50px);
  border: 6px solid hsl(calc((var(--s) + var(--r)) * 1rad) 100% 50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: inset(calc((var(--s) + var(--r)) * 50px - 200px));
  transform:  translateZ(calc(sin((var(--s) + var(--r)) * 1rad) * 100px))
}

@keyframes grow {
  from { --r: 0 }
  to { --r: 0.2 }
}
<div class="base">
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 4.8"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 4.6"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 5"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 4.4"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 5.2"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 4.2"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 5.4"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 4"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 5.6"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 3.8"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 3.6"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 3.4"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 3.2"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 0"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 3"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 0.2"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 2.8"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 0.4"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 2.6"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 0.6"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 2.4"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 0.8"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 2.2"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 1"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 2"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 1.2"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 1.8"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 1.4"></div>
  <div class="ring" style="--s: 1.6"></div>
</div>



If you want the HTML part a bit more compact, preprocessing with Pug will help; see it live.

Python, 738 bytes
import math

data = [[' '] * 100 for _ in range(30)]

for i in range(81):
    for j in range(81):
        x = -4 + i * 0.1
        y = -4 + j * 0.1
        r = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
        z = math.sin(r)

        # normal vector
        length = math.sqrt(1 + math.cos(r)**2)
        nx = -x * math.cos(r) / r / length if r else 0
        ny = -y * math.cos(r) / r / length if r else 0
        nz = 1 / length

        # light intensity
        light = (ny + nz) / math.sqrt(2)
        char = " .-:=+*#%@"[int(light * 10)]

        # project to screen
        screen_x = 50 - round(x * 6 - y * 6)
        screen_y = 12 - round(z * 5 - x * 1.5 - y * 1.5)
        data[screen_y][screen_x] = char

for row in data:
    print(''.join(row))

Attempt This Online!
ASCII art with simple lighting.
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                            ==++*******++                                           
                                      :+**###%%%%%###########**                                     
                                  -:+**##%%@%@@@%%%%%####****#####*                                 
                               .-:=+*##%%@@@@@@@@@%%##***++++**######*                              
                              .::=+**###%%%@@@@@@@%%#**+=====+**##%%%%#                             
                            .--:==++**#####%@@@@@@%##*=::::=+**#%%%%%%%%%*                          
                           .--::==+++***###**+@@@@%#++-:=+**##%%@@@@@@@%%%##                        
                         ..--::===+++****#########*######%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@%%%#                       
                     .  ..--:::===+++***#######%%%%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%%%###                    
                  :......---:::===+++****#####%%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%%%%###                 
               =:--....----:::===++++****#####%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%%%%####              
            *+=:----.-----::::====+++****######%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%%%%%%####           
  %%%%%%%##**==:--------::::=====++++****######%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%%%%%%###*+==::-- 
   %%%%%%#**+==::::---:::::====+++++*****######%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%%%%%%##*+==:--  
    %%%%###*++==::::::::::=====+++++*****######%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%%%%#**++:::   
      %%###**+++==:::::=======++++++****#######%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%%%###*+==     
         ###**+++==========+++++++******#######%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%%%##**        
            ***++++++++=+++++++++*******#######%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@%%%%#           
                   +++++++++++*********#######%%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                  
                         ++**********#########%%%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                        
                             ****###########%%%%%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                            
                                ###########%%%%%%%%%%%%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@                               
                                  #########%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%@@                                 
                                     ###########%%%%%%%%%%####%%                                    
                                        ##*++==::----::=++*##                                       
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    


The lighting is a nice touch.

People are going to think you can't draw graphics in python!

Floater (385 pixels)

Enlarged:

Image after execution:

Higher fidelity shot by changing the first pushed value from 6 to 12:

Bonus work-in-progress shot:

[Edit] Actually this can be smaller, but right now I can't be bothered. I spotted an unused value initialized on memory location 4.

Now that is an obscure language!

Only because I lack the marketing skills. And I lost my esolang.org login to boot!

And I regained esolang wiki control

JavaScript
This was generated almost entirely by v0, an LLM programming assistant. I'm marking it as community wiki since there's currently no consensus on AI-generated answers. Maybe this will get some discussion moving.
After clicking on "Run code snippet" below you might have to scroll the iframe to see the hat. Click on "Full page" to see a bigger view of it.


const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;

function drawPlot(rotationX, rotationY) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  const scale = Math.min(width, height) / 8;
  const centerX = width / 2;
  const centerY = height / 2;

  // Create a depth buffer to handle overlapping points
  const depthBuffer = new Array(width * height).fill(Infinity);

  for (let x = -4; x <= 4; x += 0.1) {
    for (let y = -4; y <= 4; y += 0.1) {
      const distance = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
      const z = Math.sin(distance);

      // 3D rotation
      const rotatedX = x * Math.cos(rotationY) + y * Math.sin(rotationY);
      const rotatedY = -x * Math.sin(rotationY) * Math.sin(rotationX) + y * Math.cos(rotationY) * Math.sin(rotationX) + z * Math.cos(rotationX);
      const rotatedZ = x * Math.sin(rotationY) * Math.cos(rotationX) - y * Math.cos(rotationY) * Math.cos(rotationX) + z * Math.sin(rotationX);

      // Project 3D to 2D
      const screenX = Math.round(centerX + rotatedX * scale);
      const screenY = Math.round(centerY - rotatedZ * scale);

      // Check if this point is closer than the previous point at this pixel
      const bufferIndex = screenY * width + screenX;
      if (screenX >= 0 && screenX < width && screenY >= 0 && screenY < height && rotatedY < depthBuffer[bufferIndex]) {
        depthBuffer[bufferIndex] = rotatedY;

        // Map z value to color
        const r = Math.floor(255 * (0.5 + 0.5 * Math.sin(Math.PI * z)));
        const g = Math.floor(255 * (0.5 + 0.5 * Math.cos(Math.PI * z / 2)));
        const b = Math.floor(255 * (0.5 + 0.5 * Math.sin(Math.PI * z / 4)));

        // Apply depth shading
        const depthFactor = 0.5 + (rotatedY + 4) / 8; // Normalize to 0.5-1 range
        ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${r * depthFactor},${g * depthFactor},${b * depthFactor})`;
        ctx.fillRect(screenX, screenY, 2, 2);
      }
    }
  }
}

let rotationY = 0;

function animate() {
  drawPlot(Math.PI / 2.5, rotationY);
  rotationY += 0.01;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
body{background-color: #1a202c;}
<canvas id=canvas width=800 height=600></canvas>




Why did you choose v0 for this?

@Simd I saw on X somebody had shown off some data visualization they had had v0 make for them and I had recently seen this question, so I just put the two together. It’s pretty nice for this sort of limited-scope task, though.

v0 initially wrote it using React and Three.js (with slick orbit controls and a sunset skybox) but I instructed it to just use canvas instead. In the translation it went from being a surface plot to a point plot and lost the interactivity. I could have tweaked it more but I ran out of free prompts for the day and anyway the result was pretty good and concise. Oddly the hardest thing was getting it to orient the plot correctly. You can see the whole v0 session here.

Scratch 3.0 + Pen extension, 58 blocks

check it out in action here
based off of Neil's answer
